# Querying last non-null values of time-series table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a time-series table which looks like the following:

```
time                |   a     | b        | c       | d
--------------------+---------+----------+---------+---------
2016-05-15 00:08:22 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 01:50:56 |         |          | 26.8301 |
2016-05-15 02:41:58 |         |          |         |            
2016-05-15 03:01:37 |         |          |         |            
2016-05-15 04:45:18 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 05:45:32 |         |          | 26.9688 |
2016-05-15 06:01:48 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 07:47:56 |         |          |         | 27.1269
2016-05-15 08:01:22 |         |          |         |            
2016-05-15 09:35:36 | 26.7441 | 29.8398  |         | 26.9981
2016-05-15 10:08:53 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 11:08:30 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 12:14:59 |         |          |         |         
2016-05-15 13:33:36 | 27.4277 | 29.7695  |         |                            
2016-05-15 14:36:36 | 27.4688 | 29.6836  |         |            
2016-05-15 15:37:36 | 27.1016 |          |         |
```

I want to return last non-null values of every column:

like this (best option):

```
time                | column   | value
--------------------+--------- +-------
2016-05-15 15:37:36 | a        | 27.1016
2016-05-15 14:36:36 | b        | 29.6836
2016-05-15 05:45:32 | c        | 26.9688
2016-05-15 09:35:36 | d        | 26.9981
```

like this:

```
column   | value
-------- +-------
a        | 27.1016
b        | 29.6836
c        | 26.9688
d        | 26.9981
```

or at least like this:

```
a       | b        | c       | d
--------+----------+---------+---------
27.1016 | 29.6836  | 26.9688 | 26.9981
```

Thanks!

Comment: *last non-null* last in what order?

Comment: @Miro . . . I'm confused by your data.  If this time-series data, why aren't the rows in time order?  Don't you want the most recent value?

Comment: You are totally right - there was a mistake in my data. It was supposed to be ordered. Fixing....

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot and select the last row:

```
select distinct on (v.which) t.time, v.which, v.val
from t cross join lateral
     (values (a, 'a'), (b, 'b'), (c, 'c'), (d, 'd')) v(val, which)
where v.val is not null
order by v.which, t.time desc;
```

Comment: This will return the last non nulls chronologically which is **not** what the OP wants. Check the expected output.

Comment: There was a problem with the data - the intension is correct..... Sorry about it...

Comment: This solution is neat, but for some reason, Postgres is not reusing my partial indices on data when executing it (`CREATE INDEX  "idx_nonnull_a" ON t (time, "a") WHERE "a" IS NOT NULL`). Any idea?

Comment: @Miro . . . I don't think tis is going to use any indexes.  To use indexes will be much more complicated, if that is at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another answer, but I see now that @GordonLinoff answer is better.

> ```
> with src as (
>   select '0' as pos,    1    as a, 2    as b, null as c
>   union all select '1', null as a, null as b, 7    as c
>   union all select '2', 2    as a, null as b, 3    as c
>   union all select '3', null as a, null as b, null as c
>   union all select '4', null as a, 4    as b, null as c
> ),
> n as (
>  select row_number() over() as rn, src.* from src
> )
>
> (select last_value(pos) over (order by rn desc) as timestamp, 'a' as column, last_value(a) over (order by rn desc) as value 
> from n
> where a is not null
> limit 1)
> union all
> (select last_value(pos) over (order by rn desc) as timestamp, 'b' as column, last_value(b) over (order by rn desc) as value 
> from n
> where b is not null
> limit 1)
> union all
> (select last_value(pos) over (order by rn desc) as timestamp, 'c' as column, last_value(c) over (order by rn desc) as value 
> from n
> where c is not null
> limit 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> timestamp | column | value
> :-------- | :----- | ----:
> 2         | a      |     2
> 4         | b      |     4
> 2         | c      |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e8f0f560fa4fe9581650c14caeeb9dc9)*